# Why min value in C++ print out a strange result?

Tags: c++

In this small program I want the user to prompt 5 integer, and print the min and max value. The logic seems alright, despite that, the `min` value, prints a strange negative number.

I tried to change the name of the variable wrongly thinking that 'min' may refer to the minimum integer value allowed in C++ but the result didn't change.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int numbers[5], min = 0, max = 0;
    cout << "Enter five numbers: ";        // Type a number and press enter

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cin >> numbers[i];                 // Get user input from the keyboard

        for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i ++ ) {
            if (numbers[i] < min) {
                min = numbers[i];
            } else if (numbers[i] > max) {
                max = numbers[i];
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Min " << min << "  Max " << max << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter five numbers: 4 59 3 34 3 
Min -447342104  Max 59
```

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Well, it could be done in one loop, but certainly not *nested* loops.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank'you, even trying to moving the second block out of the 'for' statement the result doesn't change.

Comment: You will want to initialize the value of min to the first number of the sequence, otherwise, it will always be zero. Unless, all the numbers in your sequence are negative. And yes, you shouldn't use nested loops.

Comment: If you enable more warnings, the compiler will report  "warning: declaration of ‘i’ shadows a previous local [-Wshadow]".

Comment: 0 is clearly not a good choice to init min or max.  Consider the alternate extreme initial values.  i.e.  "int min = INT_MAX;" and "int max = INT_MIN;"   INT_MAX and INT_MIN are declared in <climits>.

Comment: For user input (cin) consider checking the status of the conversion.  After "cin >> numbers[i];"  add "assert(cin.good());" to confirm that no input typo  occurred.

Comment: I seldom rely on my clumsy fingers to test my code.  Instead, you might consider  using "stringstream ssIn;", in place of cin.  You can then initialize with "ssIn << " 4  59  3  34  3 ",  and replace your  use of cin with  ssIn for  _repeatable_ test input that should always be submitted.  Don't forget to describe expected output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are searching for the `min`/`max` values before the array has been fully populated.

You should read the 5 integers using one loop, THEN look for the min/max values AFTER the 1st loop has finished:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numbers[5], minNum, maxNum;

    cout << "Enter five numbers: ";                                // Type a number and press enter

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cin >> numbers[i];                                         // Get user input from the keyboard
    }

    minNum = maxNum = numbers[0];

    for ( int i = 1; i < 5; i ++ ) {
        if (numbers[i] < minNum) {
            minNum = numbers[i];
        }
        if (numbers[i] > maxNum) {
            maxNum = numbers[i];
        }
    }

    cout << "Min " << minNum << "  Max " << maxNum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the standard [`std::minmax_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) algorithm instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numbers[5];

    cout << "Enter five numbers: ";                                // Type a number and press enter

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cin >> numbers[i];                                         // Get user input from the keyboard
    }

    pair<int*, int*> nums = minmax_element(numbers, numbers + 5);

    cout << "Min " << *(nums.first) << "  Max " << *(nums.second) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a *single* loop for everything, don't use *multiple* loops at all:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numbers[5], minNum = 0, maxNum = 0;

    cout << "Enter five numbers: ";        // Type a number and press enter

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        cin >> numbers[i];                 // Get user input from the keyboard

        if (i == 0) {
            minNum = maxNum = numbers[i];
        }
        else {
            if (numbers[i] < minNum) {
                minNum = numbers[i];
            }
            if (numbers[i] > maxNum) {
                maxNum = numbers[i];
            }
        }

        /* or simpler:
        minNum = std::min(minNum, numbers[i]);
        maxNum = std::max(maxNum, numbers[i]);
        */
    }

    cout << "Min " << minNum << "  Max " << maxNum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Or:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numbers[5], minNum, maxNum;

    cout << "Enter five numbers: ";        // Type a number and press enter

    cin >> numbers[0];                 // Get user input from the keyboard
    minNum = maxNum = numbers[i];

    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        cin >> numbers[i];                 // Get user input from the keyboard

        if (numbers[i] < minNum) {
            minNum = numbers[i];
        }
        if (numbers[i] > maxNum) {
            maxNum = numbers[i];
        }

        /* or simpler:
        minNum = std::min(minNum, numbers[i]);
        maxNum = std::max(maxNum, numbers[i]);
        */
    }

    cout << "Min " << minNum << "  Max " << maxNum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would at least initilize `min` and `max` with `std::numeric_limits` in the last example

Comment: @Slava I'm guessing you mean min=numeric_max and max = numeric_min? Otherwise the other way won't work.

Comment: @Chipster obviously yes